# adding fade to slide script?

Tags: javascript, slider, fade

I was wondering if someone could help me, is there a way to add fade betwene slides in this preticular script code? It targets buttons that changes images. Thanks upfront!

```
<script>
    var slideIndex1 = 1;
    showDivs1(slideIndex1);

    function plusDivs1(n) {
        showDivs1(slideIndex1 += n);
    }

    function showDivs1(n) {
        var i;
        var y = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
        if (n > y.length) {
            slideIndex1 = 1
        }
        if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex1 = y.length
        }
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            y[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        y[slideIndex1 - 1].style.display = "block";
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking to achieve is a carousel ([Bootstrap example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp))

Instead of applying `display="none"` to all these elements, if I were you I would toggle some CSS class which uses an animation or a transition .

You can learn more about CSS animations [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) ([just an example of what you can achieve with vanilla CSS](https://codepen.io/leemark/pen/DvliI))

It can be tedious to create a working and responsive carousel, hence I would suggest you either to use a premade solution, or use an util library such as [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp), which provides plenty of animations.